# My friend said she says "やる時やる." a lot. What's the translation to english?

Tags: expressions

やる時{とき}やるじゃん！  (Yaru toki yaru jan!)

I think the meaning is something like "When you want to do something, you do it".

Or maybe, "When you are about to do something, you just do it."

This is a positive expression?

Does it mean you have confidence in what you do? Or that you do it without thinking first?

Thanks!

Comment: @Flaw what is じゃん in this instance?

Comment: I think you misheard "やる時はやる".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: 「じゃん」 is a short form of 「じゃない」, often used to confirm something, like saying "isn't it?" in English. So in this case I would take it as ending the sentence with "right?"

Comment: I thought it might be short for 「じゃない」 but didn't realize that had use as a question... I guess it makes sense, the way informal language typically works. @sawa what is the pronunciation for 「時は」 ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: 時は is pronounced as ときわ, but it can sound like ときゃ in a fast (and a little sloppy) speech.

Answer (score 9):

やる時はやる means "When [you/I] (really decide to) do things, [you/I] **do** them". The nuance is that you don't just **try** to do them, you do them and do them well.

The expression conveys that a person has the ability to do things well when they put their minds to it, even if they are slow to act in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

I think it means to get things done when necessary. Here is an example taken from [here](http://www.websaru.info/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A.html):

花子はオットリしているようで、やるときはやる人間だ。

Hanako seems quiet, but she get things done when it's necessary.

Comment: OK, maybe not just when necessary but also with an emphasis on "well", as pointed out by Hyperworm.